Youtube API Get UpdatedAt From API Response
Recently i started my POC Youtube API, As user i can see youtube related all datas.
However i am trying to search last video last modified date, but it is missing.
PublishedAt is available but UpdateAt is missing
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=youtubeid&key=mykey&part=update,snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status
Could you some one confirm, youtube api not providing last modified details in the API response
I spent my few hours in the google youtube developer articles and documentation, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos
However there is updateAt is available for comments, but for youtube video last updated not available in the API Response

What video update are you interested in? Please provide examples. Just to make sure, you are looking for updateAt for other channels than yours, right?
